# Generic Sort- comparision problem

Tags: java

```
public class GenericSort<G extends Comparable> {
     private G[] integerarray;
     public GenericSort(G[] inputarray){
      this.integerarray = inputarray;
      //check empty array
      if (integerarray ==null || integerarray.length==0){return;}
      quickSort(0,integerarray.length-1);
     }

     public void quickSort(int low, int high){
      int i = low;
      int j = high;
      //set Pivot
      G pivot = integerarray[low + (high-low)/2];
      while(i<=j){
       //check left
       while(integerarray[i]<pivot){i++;}
       //check right
       while(pivot<integerarray[j]){j--;}
       //swap
        if(i<=j){
         G temp = integerarray[i];
         integerarray[i] = integerarray[j];
         integerarray[j] = temp;
         i++;
         j--;
        }
      }
      //recursion
      if(low<j){quickSort(low,j);}
      if(i<high){quickSort(i,high);}
     }
}
```

here the line:

```
while(integerarray[i]<pivot) {
    i++;
} & 

while(integerarray[i]<pivot){i++;}
```

is giving error because comarision is not allowed between unknown types. So i extended G from comparable. Still doesnt work. How to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

`<` and `>` are only for primitives. If your class implements `Comparable`, use it's `compareTo` method and compare the result to 0

- [compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29)

Comment: thankyou, it works but it gives a warning::the method compareTo(Object) belongs to raw type Comparable.Reference to Generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized

Comment: @Gopal, try `<G extends Comparable<G>>` instead of `<G extends Comparable>`

Comment: @Gopal, The extra type parameter improves the compile-time type safety.  For example it prevents you from saying `pivot.compareTo(42)`.  This would compile because 42 is an instance of `Integer` which extends `Comparable` but then if `G` was actually `String` you would get a `ClassCastException` at run-time.

Comment: Because the definition of Comparable requires it to have a type parameter.

Comment: It should be `<G extends Comparable<? super G>>`... that allows a `G` that implements raw `Comparable` instead of `Comparable<G>` and it allows `G` to be a subtype of a type that is `Comparable`.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing Comparable does not allow you to use comparison operators >, <, ==. It is not C++, man. :(

Instead you have to use compareTo() method defined in Comparable interface.

And yet another comment. Could you please distinguish between 2 absolutely different things like "does not work" and "does not compile". In your case you cannot compile your code. When your code is not compiled you actually do not have to post so large code snippet. As less text and smaller code snippet you send as higher a chance to get good answer.

Good luck!

PS: check Collections.sort() as a reference. It does exactly what your are trying to implement.

Comment: thankyou, it works but it gives a warning::the method compareTo(Object) belongs to raw type Comparable.Reference to Generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized

Answer (score 2):

you cant compare objects with operators like <, > or ==.
Comparable is an interface with specifies the method compareTo(Object o)
[Look here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: You can actually compare objects with ==. Unfortunately it usually does something different than what you would think it does :)